Mysql query join to subquery with SUM logic
why i get only one row as result:
SELECT
    u.id AS id,
    u.name AS name,
    SUM(p.totalSeen + q.totalSeen) AS totalSeen,
    SUM(p.totalLikes + q.totalLikes) AS totalLikes,
    SUM(p.totalShares + q.totalShares) AS totalShares,
    SUM(p.totalBookmarks + q.totalBookmarks) AS totalBookmarks,
    p.totalDownloads,
    p.totalFeedbacks
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pu.id AS id,
        SUM(IF(pe.event = 'SEEN', 1, 0)) AS totalSeen,
        SUM(IF(pe.event = 'LIKE', 1, 0)) AS totalLikes,
        SUM(IF(pe.event = 'SHARE', 1, 0)) AS totalShares,
        SUM(IF(pe.event = 'BOOKMARK', 1, 0)) AS totalBookmarks,
        SUM(IF(pe.event = 'DOWNLOAD', 1, 0)) AS totalDownloads,
        SUM(IF(pe.event = 'FEEDBACK', 1, 0)) AS totalFeedbacks
    FROM postEvents pe  
    JOIN users pu ON pu.id = pe.userId AND pu.deletedOn IS NULL
    GROUP BY pu.id
) p ON p.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        qu.id AS id,
        SUM(IF(qe.event = 'SEEN', 1, 0)) AS totalSeen,
        SUM(IF(qe.event = 'LIKE', 1, 0)) AS totalLikes,
        SUM(IF(qe.event = 'SHARE', 1, 0)) AS totalShares,
        SUM(IF(qe.event = 'BOOKMARK', 1, 0)) AS totalBookmarks
    FROM questionEvents qe  
    JOIN users qu ON qu.id = qe.userId AND qu.deletedOn IS NULL
    GROUP BY qu.id
) q ON q.id = u.id;

I need to do sum metrics in subqueries, and in subqueries some filters should be implemented like deletedOn IS NULL
THX

you are missing a GROUP BY id,name,    p.totalDownloads,
p.totalFeedbacks

True, thank you very much @nbk
